# Find an element by ID using another element's className

Tags: jquery

I have a menu - each menu item has a class name. When I click on the menu item I am using JQuery to find a div with a matching ID name. The problem is that the search isn't strict. If something has a class name like elo-1 and I have div IDs name elo-1 and elo-11 there is no way (the way I am doing this) to get just elo-1.

I would like to get an exact match. I would like to click on elo-1 and only get elo-1, not elo-1, elo-11, elo-12, etc. Anyone have any ideas?

Here is teh code I am using:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

    var myLayoutId = $(this).attr("layoutId");


    $("#start_page").show().siblings().hide();
    $("#navBar").hide();
    $("#refs").hide();

    $("li").click(function() {
        var thisID = $(this).attr("class");
        $("#mainBdy div:#"+thisID).show().siblings().hide();
        $('#mainBdy div[id^="'+thisID+'"]').show();


        $("#mainBdy div:#"+thisID).css("width","30%");
        $("#mainBdy div:#"+thisID).css("margin-left","-80px");
        $("#mainBdy div:#"+thisID).css("margin-top","-50px");
        $("#mainBdy div:#"+thisID).css("float","left");


    });


    $("#start_page_accept").click(function() {
        $("#navBar").show();
        $("#refs").show();
        $("#start_page").hide().next().show();
    });

    $("#menu").collapsible({
        effect: "slide",             // The effect to use when expanding and collapsing the menu. 
        initialCollapse: true       // When true, collapses the menu when the page loads.
    });

});
```

Comment: To just select elo-1, use `$("#elo-1")`. Also, you have invalid syntax here: `div:#"+thisID` remove `:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your selector to avoid starts-with matching:

```javascript
$('#mainBdy div[id^="'+thisID+'"]').show();
```

This matches anything that *starts with* your value, which is not what you want:

```javascript
$('#mainBdy div[id="'+thisID+'"]').show();
```

This matches only those items whose id attribute is *equal* to your value.

#### Additional Suggestions

Note also that you're binding to individual list items:

```javascript
$("li").click();
```

This could become tasking to your app since you're adding an event handler for every new list item that is placed on the page. *Event Delegation* is a far better approach, and consists of adding one event handler to the ancestor element, using event-bubbling to respond to events on nested items.

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li class="edo-1">Edoine Mashlup</li>
</ul>
```

Suppose this was our markup (toss in another 100 list items for good measure), the following would be our event-delegation instruction:

```javascript
$("#list").on("click", "li", function () {
    $("#" + this.className).show().css({
        width:      '30%',
        marginLeft: '-80px',
        marginTop:  '-50px',
        float:      'left'
    })
    .siblings().hide();
});
```

Anytime a click event occurs *on*, or *within* our `#list` element, we will evaluate whether the target (the element that received the click) matches our selector `li`. If it does, we trigger our function - otherwise, we ignore it and let it bubble up the DOM.

Comment: Thank you. I used your suggestions (altered a bit). This is my changes:   $("#navBar").on("click", "li", function () {
   $('#mainBdy div[class="'+this.id+'"]').show().css({
    width:      '30%',
    marginLeft: '-80px',
    marginTop:  '-50px',
    float:      'left'
   })
   .siblings().hide();
   $('#mainBdy div[class="'+this.id+'"]').show();
  });

Answer (score 7):

Replace this:

```
    $("#mainBdy div:#"+thisID).show().siblings().hide();
    $('#mainBdy div[id^="'+thisID+'"]').show();


    $("#mainBdy div:#"+thisID).css("width","30%");
    $("#mainBdy div:#"+thisID).css("margin-left","-80px");
    $("#mainBdy div:#"+thisID).css("margin-top","-50px");
    $("#mainBdy div:#"+thisID).css("float","left");
```

With this:

```
$('#' + thisID).show().css({
    'width': '30%',
    'margin-left': '-80px',
    'margin-top': '-50px',
    'float': 'left'
}).siblings().hide();
```

A couple of notes:

- Chaining in jQuery is super powerful and avoids re-querying the DOM if you are going to do multiple things with the same element. You could likewise store the results of a jQuery search doing something like `var $div = $('#' + thisID);` - in either case, you just don't want to do the same selector over and over.
- IDs are supposed to be unique in the document, so I am assuming there is only one element with an ID of "elo-1" in the document. If that's true, which it should be, doing a complicated selector like `'#mainBdy div[id^="'+thisID+'"]'` is just stopping jQuery from being able to use the native `getElementById` which is  a gallizion times more effective (not to mention cleaner).
- As you can see, `css` accepts an object so you don't have to call it more than once. I would personally simply add a class to the menu item and handle the style in my stylesheet. It is much easier from a maintainability standpoint.

Comment: you  would have to use `.end()` to get back to the correct div.. or chain css before traversing to the siblings

Comment: @wirey oops, just caught that. fixed.